# Select string that has at least 2 alphabetic characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to make a select that returns only the strings that contain at least 2 alphabetic characters. The string can contain any combination of characters

```
ID Name
1  John 
2  John2
3  2
4  /
5  12-
6  JW
7  Jw1
8  ,
```

Comment: Yes, if it has 2 alphabets it should be returned. I don't need to make such a complex filtering, because most of the names that are jiberish are mostly symbols and have maybe 1 alphabetic character

Comment: So,2 alphabetic characters anywhere in the string ? So 'J876543ohn' is OK ? Or is it a minimum of two alphabetic characters next to each other ?

Comment: @BriteSponge now I am curious to know how to return a minimum of two alphabetic characters next to each other

Comment: If you need it then try '[[:alpha:]]{2,}'.

Answer (score 8):

```
where regexp_like(str, '[a-z].*[a-z]', 'i');
```

should do it.

The `'i'` parameter (specific to Oracle SQL regex functions) makes it case-insensitive.

Explanation: https://regex101.com/r/OYec02/1

Comment: I just wanted to ask you about 'i'... Seems to do the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 11g or later (and you should be) you can use `regexp_count()` to do this:

```
where regexp_count(txt, '[a-z]', 1, 'i') >= 2
```

This is handy where the number of characters you want to match is larger than two.

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014)